# ASP.NET Routing after execute event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, routes, webforms

I'm using Routing in an ASP.NET 4 WebForms web application.

Is there an event which gets fired after the routes in RouteTable have been evaluated and executed?

PostRequestHandlerExecute is possible, but then the handler has already been executed, is there something in between?

Answer (score 0):

There are two events PostResolveRequestCache and the PostMapRequestHandler.

[image: ASP routing request pipeline]

Detailed explanation how Routing affects request pipeline you can find here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx